# ESXi with 1 public IP address

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a dedicated server with online.net, and I am setting up esxi 6.0, but I want to have multiple VMs with internet access as well as port forwarding. I have KVM/Console access to the server. I have tried using pfSense in a VM as a router, and then setting up a NAT network . But I can't figure out how to assign it my one public IP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Speak to support at your provider?

Comment: STAHP!!! Don't do this. Get more IPs or just use a hardware router/firewall.

Comment: You need to use failover IPs for your VMs.

Comment: I have gone with multple VMs and 1 IP for management network, and 1 IP for a router VM.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, because you need one address for the ESXi management alone.
For the pfSense router VM you need a sencond public IP address.

Instructions specific to online.net are here:
http://documentation.online.net/en/serveur-dedie/systemes-d_exploitation/vmware_vsphere_hypervisor_esxi_english

Answer (score 0):

You *NEED* one address for ESXi itself and you can obvious setup some form of NAT router inside a VM but I can't think of any way you can do this in a supportable way with a single IP. The reason being that yes you can set the ESXi's IP via the KVM and that could be a non-routable IP but you need to be able to connect the non-Web-Client to that just to setup your routing VM.

Comment: Why would the non-web-client be required to setup the routing VM?

Comment: Wait, nevermind.. It's far too early and I've clearly not had enough sleep/caffeine.